# Python to exe using cx_Freeze

Tags: python, syntax, exe

I am following 'thenewboston''s tutorial on how to change a .py to a .exe and i've done the setup.py like he has but then when I type 'python setup.py build' into CMD it says I have a syntax error. I'm not sure what is wrong with the code but it says there is an error. Please help?

```
import cx_Freeze

cx_Freeze.executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("Inspire.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Inspire"
    options={"build_exe":{"packages":["os","sys","random","time"]}}
    description="A text-based RPG game"
    executables=executables
    )
```

The error is:
File setup.py line 7

```
options={"build_exe":{"packages":["os","sys","random","time"]}}
      ^
Syntax error: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing commas between your keyword arguments.

Try this instead!

```
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Inspire",
    options={"build_exe":{"packages":["os","sys","random","time"]}},
    description="A text-based RPG game",
    executables=executables
    )
```

Comment: That part is fixed but know it says 'executables' is not defined.                                   NameError: name 'executables' is not defined

Comment: You have not created a 'executables' object, so it is throwing that error.  You can try changing executables=executables to executables=[cx_Freeze.Executable("Inspire.py")]

Comment: Thank you, not sure why there were errors it worked for the person in the video. It works now thank you.

Comment: @Nicolas: Feel free to accept my answer if it worked.